# using countif with named range

Tags: excel, countif, named-ranges

I am attempting to count the number of occurrences entries in a column that are referenced in a named range.

column J contains a list of locations.  I created a named range "Locations".

I am using =COUNTIF(J6:J217,locations), but the result is only returning results for some of the locations, and only 1 occurrence of the value, instead of each occurrence.

How can I return a count of all the occurrences of the values referenced in my named range "Locations"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT to iterate the list:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(J6:J217,locations))
```